# Unity Api Compability Level is .NET Standard 2 but Visual Studio keeps using .NET v4.7.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity 2020.1.1f1 , I recently noticed I'm using all of .NET 4.x features, new syntax like Auto-property initializers as in `public int Health { get; set; } = 100;` and so many others mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-modify-the-target-framework-and-platform-toolset?view=msvc-170)

I get this for clrver command on Developer Command Prompt

```
Microsoft (R) .NET CLR Version Tool Version 4.7.2558.0 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Versions installed on the machine: v2.0.50727 v4.0.30319
```

Unity Player Settings, API Compatibility Level is .NET Standard 2.0

I've changed Assembly-CSharp.csproj v4.7.1 to v2.0 but it discards my changes and goes back to 4.7.1

I'm targeting mobile devices, I think .NET 2.0 is better for me but I don't know if whether Unity is actually using .NET 2 or .NET 4, since Unity Settings is set to use .NET Standard 2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is to update the NET version of VS: Project -> Properties.

Modify the .NET version used by the Unity project.

1. In the Unity editor, click the menu Edit -> Project Setting -> Player.
2. Select the corresponding .NET version in Scripting Runtime Version*.

[image]

reference link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html.

Close VS. Check whether the Unity-related components are installed on the VS installer, and check it.

[image]

At this time, please check whether the Visual Studio Editor exists in the Unity of the current project: Window → Package Manager.

[image]

[image]

If it does not exist, switch Packages:Unity Registry in Package Manager, search for Visual Studio Editor, and click Install in the lower right corner.

[image]

Finally, Edit → Preferences... → External Tools, the selection box on the right side of the External Script Editor. Check the currently installed version of VS.

[image]

Reference document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-and-known-issues-visual-studio-tools-for-unity#incompatible-project-in-visual-studio.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: what version of unity are you using? I don't have that option which seems to be actually the solution to my problem, I'm using 2020

Comment: @Alireza Jamali I re-edited the answer. You can have a try. thanks.

Comment: thanks man but I have Visual Studio Editor in package manager and also External Tools is showing Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, I've searched the option in your picture, it was removed at newer versions of unity, the "Api Compability Level" is the only option related to .NET version of the project, my visual studio is using .NET 4 unlike the stated use of .NET 2 at Unity Settings, I don't think there's anything I can do about that

Comment: @Alireza Jamali In Unity 2019, it is no longer possible to switch to the old .NET 3.5 runtime. The only runtime is .NET 4.x.Unity official documentation: https://docs.unity.cn/cn/current/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html

Comment: it did not solve the problem but was helpful